# Google maps placemark doesn't replace old placemark

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, geocoding, google-maps-markers

I'm developing a web page with a Google Maps application and there is something that I'm having trouble with. As it stands, the web page has a functional map (without any layers) and a search bar. I'm new to programming so hopefully there is a quick fix that I'm missing.

When I look up an address, the placemark is is positioned where it is supposed to be. However, when I make a second search with a different address, the placemark of the first search remains visible so that there are two placemarks on the screen. How can I make a new placemark replace the old one?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var geocoder;
    var map; 
    var marker;
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder ();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng (55.1667, -114.4000);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 5,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({map:map});
        }
    function codeAddress () {
        var address = document.getElementById ("address").value;
        geocoder.geocode ( { 'address': address}, function(results, status)                              {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)  {
            map.setCenter(results [0].geometry.location);
            marker.setposition(results [0].geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(16);
            } 
        else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                }
    }); 
                            }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post some code to illustrate your implementation?  I expect it's an issue to do with 'closures' but without seeing the code it's impossible to tell...

Comment: I've updated the question to include the code for the map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve what you describe is with a global `marker` variable. Since the `codeAddress` function is calling `new google.maps.Marker` every time it runs, you will get a new marker each time.

Instead, use the `setPosition` function of the global marker to move it around.

```
    var geocoder;
    var map; 

    // ADDED
    var marker;

  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder ();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng (55.1667, -114.4000);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 5,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);

     // ADDED
     marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map });
  }
    function codeAddress () {
        var address = document.getElementById ("address").value;
        geocoder.geocode ( { 'address': address}, function(results, status)  {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)  {
            map.setCenter(results [0].geometry.location);

            // CHANGED
            marker.setPosition(results [0].geometry.location);

            map.setZoom(16);
        } 
        else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: I tried what you have suggested, but now, there is no placemark added at all. I've updated my question to show my new code

Comment: Javascript is case-sensitive, replace `setposition` with `setPosition` :)